# Metaprogramming on web server

Tags: javascript, server-side-scripting, client-side-scripting

From time to time, I find myself writing server code that produces JavaScript code as the output result.

I can point out why it is really bad:

- Inextricable tie between server code and client code.
- Can render client code un-reusable.

But sometimes, it just seems to make sense.

And isn't it kinda sorta interesting?

I guess the question is, is writing server code that produces JavaScript code a really bad practice, or "does everyone do it"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not necessarily a bad practice, if it makes sense producing JavaScript that way. But with technologies moving more towards richer interfaces that rely more and more on JavaScript I think a good separation between the server and the client side is possible and necessary.

[JSON](http://json.org/) as the exchange format is imho a very good way to achieve this separation. Instead of generating JavaScript that contains data from the server side you just use a lightweight exchange format, that provides all these data. That keeps the client code clean *and* you don't have to generate any other JavaScript on the server except for the JSON objects (which is really easy in most languages).